# SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission not granted and not working

Tags: android, permissions

My app is a media player, but it has a feature to set alarms, so users can wake up to their favorite music.
Since Android 12 I have this permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

When I need to schedule an alarm I'm calling this code

```
public static boolean isScheduleExactAlarmPermissionEnabled(final Context context) {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

and if the permission isn't granted then I'm asking for the permission like this:

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM);
```

Unfortunately, this code isn't doing anything. There's no permission popup displayed. When I go to the device permission settings for my app, on Android 13 or 14 I don't see this permission.
If I open the Alarms & Reminder device screen, I don't see my app in the listed apps.

What am I missing here? It looks like this permission isn't working like the other permissions

Comment: Did you look into [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#canScheduleExactAlarms())?
Alarm manager has a function to check `canScheduleExactAlarms ()`

Comment: How does that help here? I'm asking how to be able to grant the permission? It's not granted and doesn't seem to allow me to ask for this permission

Answer (score 2):

In Android 12, user does not need to grant permission for `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM`. It only needs to be defined in Manifest.
I have tried the following code and it works for Android 12.

manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

Activity

```
val manager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(this, AlarmManager::class.java)
    if (manager?.canScheduleExactAlarms() == false) {
        Intent().also {
            it.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM
            startActivity(it)
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate: can schedule it")
    }
```

In Android 13 as well I tried and it is working. User needs to ask permission by calling

```
Intent().also {
            it.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM
            startActivity(it)
        }
```

Logcat

```
D  onCreate: can schedule it
```

[image: Alarm and Reminder settings]

Comment: Unfortunately this only opens the list of apps for Alarms & reminders and my app is not in the list

Comment: @user1026605 Exactly my problem too. Is there a way to set my app as an alarm clock/reminder app?

Comment: If your app is not on the list it is either not installed -OR- you have the permission USE_EXACT_ALARM defined in your AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1):

To show the Dialog for your app you need to add the package name as the data value

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
```

But I not know HOW add the app to the "Alarms & reminders" app list, that seems only contains Google Apps.

[image]